# Can Neurons be connected in Series and will that pattern create huge voltage in human body?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, neuron

We have learned in Physics that when multiple voltage sources are connected in Series , the resultant voltage becomes the summation of all voltages .
Now, my question is - Can Neurons be connected in same pattern and if it's possible , can let's say billions of neurons connected in Series , create a huge voltage in the body?
also , can the resultant voltage thus created become harmful for human body as an electrical shock?

Answer (score 3):

In a typical nervous system, no, that's not how neurons are connected at all. Neurons have a voltage across their membrane, a potential difference inside versus outside of the cell. A "connection" between neurons either involves a [chemical synapse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_synapse) where there is a gap of "outside" between the two neurons that neurotransmitters are released into (so relative to outside the potential is zero between the neurons) or [electrical synapse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_synapse) where the insides of the neurons are directly connected (so relative to each other there is no potential difference). Think also of all the other surface area of two connected neurons: to have an accumulating voltage these surfaces would also need to maintain that full voltage across the membrane. I would recommend trying to draw out a circuit diagram along the whole membrane of two connected diagrammatic neurons and I think you'll discover the problems quickly.

However, the configuration you describe is roughly how an electric eel operates to generate voltage (particularly for a strongly electric fish that is capable of damaging shocks), not with neurons exactly but with a special [electric organ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_organ_(fish)).